# google play permission policy update:-Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups

Tags: android

In my app, I was using SmsManager for sending SMS, but now google play updates their permission policy and Google Play restricts the use of high risk or sensitive permissions, including the SMS or Call Log permission groups.

I tried with the SMS Intent according to the alternatives they have given for initiate a text message, and I am able to send a message too, but app got crashed when I navigate back from the SMS intent

this is the code I'm using

```
String phoneNumber="000000000000";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));
intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsContent);
startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_CODE);
```

And on `onActivityResult()` the result code is always getting `0`
How can I solve this issue

Comment: You said the app is crashing, what is shown in LogCat?

Comment: Please put your crash log.

Comment: App crashing was due to some fatal exception and i have solved that issue , but the issue i'm facing now is on onActivityResult(), the result code is always getting 0 , so i can't confirm that the SMS is send or not.

Comment: I have tried with SmsSendObserver.SmsSendListener interface to receive the callback. but i'm getting this error

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/ from pid=29471, uid=10277 requires android.permission.READ_SMS, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: As clearly mentioned in your Logcat:  "requires android.permission.READ_SMS" you must ad READ_SMS permission to your manifest file